# Trying to open an Integration Services Package and getting Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, exception, visual-studio-2008, bids

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 on my machine. When I try to open an existing `.dtsx` file using BIDS I get the following error. I know this file is not corrupt because I can remote into a different machine and open it there with no problems. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

> An error prevented the view from loading. (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>   (System.Windows.Forms)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ComponentDiagram.CreateDdsView(Control parentControl)
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DtsComponentDiagram.CreateDdsView(Control parentControl)
>   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Controls.DdsDiagramHostControl.set_ComponentDiagram(ComponentDiagram value)
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.ControlFlowControl.set_ComponentDiagram(ComponentDiagram value)
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DtsPackageView.CreateControlFlowEditor(VsStyleToolBar pageViewToolBar)
>   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.EditorWindow.EnsureViewIsLoaded(EditorView view)

Comment: Did you install VS11 Beta? If so, then the solution for your problem is here => http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287133/325521

Comment: No. I installed Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Comment: Install sql server 2008 SP1.. It will solve the problem.

Comment: @Shiva I had not installed VS11 but what I had done several months ago was install VS2012 and that is what ultimately caused this issue.  When I uninstalled VS2012 all the dll's did not get removed so the install of VS2008 tried using those.  That was the issue that needed resolved.  I removed the folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8)that contained all those dll's and then repaired my installation of VS2008.  Tested the fix and it worked.

Comment: Great! Glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not installed VS11 but what I had done several months ago was install VS2012 and that is what ultimately caused this issue. When I uninstalled VS2012 all the dll's did not get removed so the install of VS2008 tried using those. That was the issue that needed resolved. I removed the folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8)that contained all those dll's and then repaired my installation of VS2008. Tested the fix and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8` and repairing VS2008 resolved my issue.

FYI, I had SQL Server 2014 installed and unistalled earlier, and all those DLLs still exist and caused this issue.