# Package Validation Error: 0xC020801C excel connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out. I have setup two connection managers to connect to two sheets on an excel file. Each one is used to export data to the sheet from a SQL DB. It has been running fine till last night. Now I get the error:

> ===================================
>
> Package Validation Error (Package Validation Error)
>
> ===================================
>
> Error at Export Approved Projects to Excel [Excel Dest AllData [293]]: SSIS > > Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> Error at Export Approved Projects to Excel [SSIS.Pipeline]: Excel Dest AllData failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
>
> Error at Export Approved Projects to Excel [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Error at Export Approved Projects to Excel: There were errors during task validation.
>
> Error at Package [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x8007007E.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x8007007E  Description: "The specified module could not be found.".
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>
> at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32 launchOptions)
>
> at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>
> at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

I found this answer: [Package Validation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317035/package-validation-error) which recommends changing the `Run64Bits` to `FALSE`. I did this and still get the same error.

I also found an answer (though I don't remember the link) where it said to update the `DelayValidation` on the connection manager to `TRUE`. I did this as well and still get the same error.

Then I found this one [The Specified Module could not be found. . .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460118/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception-from-hresult-0x8007007e)

But it's 5 years old and talks about it being caused by uninstalling VS2012. I actually am using VS2012 to write the project so I don't think this is it and haven't tried it yet.

Any other suggestions???

**UPDATE**

I replaced the dll as suggested and there is not improvement. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft OLE DB Service Components" Hresult: 0x8007007E Description: "The specified module could not be found.".

You may fix this by repairing [Microsoft Office Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) even if you has installed before but it seems that uninstalling some Office products or similar operations might break the Excel connectivity.